# Composer: cache private GIT repository on BitBucket

Tags: php, git, caching, composer-php

I have project X which depends on project Y, each has their own `composer.json` file. Y is held in a private GIT repository on bitbucket.

X's `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "jodes/X",
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "@stable",
        // .....
        "jodes/Y": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://bitbucket.org/Jodes/Y.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

It installs `monolog` and other public packages that are hosted on packagist quickly, but it never caches Y, so runs slowly.

How can I make it cache Y so it installs quickly?

Comment: Have you configured ssh key for your git client?

Comment: I've configured an `auth.json` that defines `http-basic` object with bitbucket username and password, if that's what you mean? It does grant access to the repository. It's just that it never caches it.

Comment: I was facing the same issue so i have to copy ssh shared key. Please find the link for documentation.https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Comment: Thanks - how would I do that? Would I remove the auth.json file altogether? (I'm on Windows using msysgit, if that's significant?).

Comment: the method that you are using @Jodes is correct. However i have one doubt that as per composer documentation, its telling it only support basic HTTP auth. i don't know if HTTPS is also supported. If possible please change the URL(https to http)  within composer.json file and check if its working or not.

Comment: In my code in my question, it already is specified as https?

Comment: change that to http and check if its working or not.

Comment: @AbhijeetKamble, that worked, thanks! You should put it in an answer and I will select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Solve your problem you have to change your HTTPS request to HTTP. As per the documentation provided by Composer, it only supports Basic HTTP authentication.

```
{
    "name": "jodes/X",
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "@stable",
        // .....
        "jodes/Y": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "http://bitbucket.org/Jodes/Y.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please find the links for documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md).